# Kafka-connect elasticsearch how to define index mappings

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using [kafka-connect-elasticsearch](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch) with a custom converter, which extends standard `JsonConverter`.
I have 250+ topics with different event types, thus i'm happy that kafka-connect automatically creates indices for me in elasticsearch.

However, I'd like to **disable all analysers except for `keyword`-analyser** (don't need full-text search here).
**How can I do that?** How and where can I **manipulate index mappings**?

In my custom converter I infer schema for my payload, convert it to kafka-connect-specific schema, and then return `new SchemaAndValue(connectSchema, connectValue)` object.
I suppose, connect-specific schema is then used to generate `mappings`, is that true?